# Firefox error: NetworkError, Sourcemap error but works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

While working with the Spotify API, works as expected with Chrome but running into an error on Firefox.

**NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: moz-extension://4a6ad998-74f5-4aa2-9a99-57349192fc19/node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js**

**Source map error: Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: moz-extension://4a6ad998-74f5-4aa2-9a99-57349192fc19/node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js
Source Map URL: moment.min.js.map**

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": { },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Basic f396e129bb444830a9662c83630409ef:fbf507fdb00f45b5b8cae2d8bea58a60",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.27.2",
            "Content-Length": 311
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
        "data": "code=AQBE5Re_bT-Fi0hlNsdi6cILu1_lnAd167WxdeYQ0roQvzGziY9Ys3RtAE4u6V8CDlh1XS4yRWfbnlMdfNBMu9yPu7ooYGhNuLibtxZjMxRdamn46XIrgJg06pykmlWazwTdcCOyLBXSjDdamuJXNXSjhQ9zYqBh_UQJaltu_42uMZSUwF__c8vLV5K12r71vYsirJFbbHvqwA2G5VZgpmcvnCKcXg&grant_type=authorization_code&reqirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 400
}
```

````
app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code || null;

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    data: queryString.stringify({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: code,
        reqirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI
    }),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Authorization: `Basic ${new Buffer.from(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`.toString('base64'))}`
    },
})
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            res.send(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)}</pre>`);
        } else res.send(response)
    })

    .catch(err => {
        res.send(err)
    });
})```
````

Comment: not the real problem, but `reqirect_uri` I guess should be reDirect

Comment: `moz-extension`... are you coding browser extensions?

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks, fixed it but the error still remains. Also, not a browser extenstion, was just trying to make an app to understand my way around Spotify's Authorization and Authentication.

Comment: Ok, in this case I think you could try disabling all firefox extensions, and then try it again.

Comment: @GrafiCode Found the issue. I was already logged into Spotify so it kept skipping the screen.